# Cython. Out of bounds error

Tags: cython, indexoutofboundsexception

I have written the following cython code to be used with the analysis of my research.

```
def jumprate(np.ndarray[FTYPE_t, ndim=1] X ,np.ndarray[LTYPE_t, ndim=1] V):

cdef np.ndarray J = np.zeros([X.shape[0]], dtype=LTYPE)
cdef np.ndarray O = np.zeros([X.shape[0]], dtype=LTYPE)
cdef np.ndarray Vel = np.zeros([X.shape[0]], dtype=FTYPE)    
cdef  long  j=0 # index of J
cdef  long  o=0# index of O
cdef  long  k = 0 # index of X
cdef  long l = 0 # counts length of sequence of same velocity sign
cdef  long  L = V.shape[0]/3
cdef  int jumpstart = 1
cdef  int jumpend = 1    
cdef  long S0 = 0    

while k <  L:  # run over position array
    if V[k]==V[k-1]: # might be a start of jump
        jumpstart = k  # Also where last oscilation ended    
        S0 = V[k]
        while V[k]==S0: # As long as velocity sign doesn't change we might be in a jump
            l += 1 # Count sequences length
            k += 1 # Update position in array
    if int(X[jumpstart]) != int(X[k]): # If start end ending point of sequence are 
                                     # in different grid squares, it's a jump
        J[j] = l # Append jump length to list 
        j += 1
        Vel[j] = (jumpstart-jumpend)/100
        O[o] = abs((jumpend-jumpstart))  # Append oscilation length to list 
        o += 1
        l = 0 
        jumpend = k # mark where last jump ended (also where new oscilation starts)
    k+=1    
return J,O,Vel
```

Notice in the definition of L at the 9th line the division by 3. I inserted it after receiving the following error at runtime

```
while V[k]==S0: # ...
IndexError: Out of bounds on buffer access (axis 0)
```

which sort of solved the problem. However, the array's X,V passed to the function have 99990 elements in them, and this solution means only the first 33330 are used. At first i though i should simply change the type from int to long but it did not help.

Can anyone suggest a remedy for the problem?

Those who are interested in the purpose of the code, it is meant to follow the trajectory of an atom (the array X), which oscillates in a potential well some times, and jumps from one well to another at other times. The function "jumprate" returns two arrays which holds the lengths (in time) of the alternating jumping and oscillatory motion sequences.

Comment: I can't really work out what the `while V[k]==S0` loop is doing - depending on what is in `V`, couldn't `k` grow arbitrarily large here, leading to this `IndexError`, whatever the value of `L`?  Maybe you should add a check in this loop to make sure `k` doesn't go past the end of the array.

Comment: Hi James. S0 refers to the direction of motion. It takes either 1 or -1. I define a jump as a sequence that among other requirements maintain the same sign of velocity. k is limited by the size of V which is 99990 at most. But i will check it regardless.

Comment: Suppose the last two elements of `V` are the same.  Then, on the final value of `k`, the `while V[k]==0` loop will be entered.  Inside this loop, `k` will be incremented, and then the loop condition will be checked.  Trying to evaluate `V[k]` will cause an `IndexError`.  Also, when the main loop is entered, `k` is zero, so `if V[k] == V[k-1]` is checking whether the first and last elements of `V` (`V[0]` and `V[-1]`) are the same - is that really what is intended?

Comment: Thanks James. I followed your advice and added a printout of k through out the loop. Indeed, i should have added a check at the end to make sure k doesn't exceed it limit. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

`k` is initialized with `0`, and you are trying to access `V[k -1]` of a numpy array in

```
while k <  L:  # run over position array
    if V[k]==V[k-1]: # might be a start of jump
```